# querying freebase api from emacs

Tags: curl, emacs, freebase

I have the following Emacs Lisp which builds up a query to Freebase.  If I copy and paste the URL it generates into my browser *OR* a commandline `curl` I get the results I would expect:

> curl -X GET https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/search?query=Oil%20on%20Canvas&filter=(any%20type%3avisual_art%2fvisual_art_medium) ... *this works*.

but I can't make it work from within Emacs:

```
(require 'url)
(defvar fb-url "https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/search")

(defvar materials-type "(any type:visual_art/visual_art_medium)")

(defun fbquery (type str)
  (let ((url-request-method "GET")


        (url-request-data (concat "?query=" (url-hexify-string str)
                                  "&filter=" (url-hexify-string type))))
    (url-retrieve (concat fb-url)
                  (lambda (status) (switch-to-buffer (current-buffer))))))

(setq url-debug t)

(fbquery materials-type "Oil on Canvas")
```

I get back:

`HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request` ... `Your client has issued a malformed or illegal request.  That's all we know.`.

Can you help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the problem is related to intepretation of variable `url-request-data`

Following code works for me

```
(defun fbquery (type str)
  (let ((url-request-method "GET")
        (foo (concat "?query=" (url-hexify-string str)
                     "&filter=" (url-hexify-string type))))
    (url-retrieve (concat fb-url foo)
                  (lambda (status) (switch-to-buffer (current-buffer))))))
```

Please note that I renamed that variable (to avoid the error) and concat-ed it to url

Comment: Thanks!  I thought I tried everything but I guess not this combo!